# Prolog counting digits in a list

Tags: prolog

I was wondering if you could help me out with this. I need to make a script  that counts the amount of digits in a list. Here is an example:

```
amount([234,12,4356],L)
```

should result in:

```
 L=[c(234,3),c(12,2),c(4356,4)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the length of atom and make it head of your resulting variable along with that atom :

```
 count(List,X):-
    counter(List,X).

counter([],[]).
counter([H|T],[(H,Z)|X]):-
    atom_length(H,Z),
    counter(T,X).
```

So a query:

```
   ?- count([234,12,4356],L).
    L = [(234, 3),  (12, 2),  (4356, 4)].
```